# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting this error in condiotional operator.

```
string remarks="";
AddDgvNew[6, i].Value==null?remarks="":remarks=AddDgvNew[6,i].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: My suggestion is to add to the Title of your Question something like this: 'in the conditional operator (?:)'. I think it will help to find your question as the conditional context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
string remarks = AddDgvNew[6, i].Value==null?"":AddDgvNew[6,i].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 21):

Yes - because you're not *doing* anything with the result of the conditional expression. You've got a conditional expression which is trying to be a whole statement. In a simpler version:

```
bool condition = true;
int x = 10;
int y = 5;

// This is invalid
condition ? x : y;
```

What did you want to *do* with the result of the conditional expression? If the point was to assign it to a variable, then you need to do that. Currently you have *two* separate statements: one declares `remarks` and assigns it a value; the second is *just* the conditional expression.

If you're trying to do something else, you'll need to clarify what you're looking for.